# Can (or should) I use ActionLink() in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to add error message to ModelState like below:

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, string.Format("An account with the mobile or email you have specified already exists. If you have forgotten your password, please {0} it.", Html.ActionLink("Reset", "Reset", "Account")));
```

First of all how to do this? and btw, is doing this way appropriate in MVC pattern?

Or should I add a key to ModelState and let the view pick it up and generate the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The view should do stuff like that IMO, you set your model to reflect what happened and let your view make the decision about how to present the UI. After all you may decide to change how the link is displayed and you don't really want to change your controller when it's just a UI change.

Comment: I agree. Now I'm trying to do just that; however, still no luck in specifying the error message for a key within modelState from a view.

Comment: have you looked at model validation attributes?

Comment: I don't think This can be achieved via attributes. This is dynamic validation (checking whether user exists).

Comment: Btw, I have resorted to ViewData (in controller) + AddModelError (in view) approach, and it has started working. But not rendering the way I like it to be.